# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' and map of undefined React Hooks props problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a Json file to be fetched.
I fetched the data and can get the data in the console from App.js. But when I pass the data as props to my child component, it gives me an empty array and does not display the items. What could be the mistake here ?
My json data and components are below

```
App.js

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import ProcessContainer from "./components/AdoptionProcess/ProcessContainer";


function App() {
  const [adoptionProcess, setAdoptionProcess] = useState([])

  async function fetchAsync () {
    let response = await fetch('./data.json');
    let data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }
  
  fetchAsync()
      .then(data => setAdoptionProcess(data))

      useEffect(() => {
        fetchAsync()
      },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
    <ProcessContainer adoptionProcess={adoptionProcess}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
ProcessContainer.js

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ProcessItems from "./ProcessItems";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const ProcessContainer = ({adoptionProcess}) => {
  console.log(adoptionProcess)  // -> gives and empty array here


  return (
    <Container>
      <Row className="adoptionContainer py-5">
        <Col sm={12}>
          <h1>{adoptionProcess && adoptionProcess.adoptionProcessTitle.title}</h1>
          <Row className="mt-5 items">
            {adoptionProcess && adoptionProcess.adoptionProcessItems.map((process) => (
              <ProcessItems 
                img={process.img}
                text={process.text}
                firstDescription={process.firstDescription}
                secondDescription={process.secondDescription}
              />
            ))}
          </Row>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default ProcessContainer;
```

```
ProcessItems.js

import React from "react";
import { Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./AdoptionProcess.css";

const ProcessItems = ({
  img,
  text,
  firstDescription,
  secondDescription
}) => {
  return (
    <Col lg={4} className="mb-5">
      <img src={img} alt="img" className="mb-3" />
      <p>{text}</p>
      <span>{firstDescription}</span> <br />
      <span>{secondDescription}</span>
    </Col>
  );
};

export default ProcessItems;
```

```
data.json

{
    "adoptionProcessItems": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "img": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2e/23/d3/2e23d3827c8293c27cea544a8acbcd59.jpg",
            "text": "Find Your Pet",
            "firstDescription": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem",
            "secondDescription": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "img": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/5f/80/85/5f80854fd1475958717a19e345695942.jpg",
            "text": "Find Your Pet",
            "firstDescription": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem",
            "secondDescription": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "img": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2e/23/d3/2e23d3827c8293c27cea544a8acbcd59.jpg",
            "text": "Find Your Pet",
            "firstDescription": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem",
            "secondDescription": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem"
          }
    ],
    "adoptionProcessTitle" : {
        "title" : "Pet Adoption Process"
      }
  }
```

the visual will be like this
[image]

Comment: Please create codesandbox link of your problem

Comment: sure
https://codesandbox.io/s/new-monad-oreg5
https://codesandbox.io/s/new-monad-oreg5?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes, you have in your code.

1. Data returns object so please add initial state as an object.

```
const [adoptionProcess, setAdoptionProcess] = useState({});
```

2. Adding async operation required loading flag

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const data = await fetchAsync();
      setAdoptionProcess(data);
      setLoading(false);
    })();
  }, []);
```

Why do I need to add a loading flag?

Because when your async operation is going on your `processContainer` will get the `{}` empty object as your adoption process and now you are accessing the `adoptionProcess.adoptionProcessTitle.title` but the `adoptionProcess` is empty so you are accessing the undefined of title and you got the same error in your response.

After the async operations are finished the state will be set and it causes the rerender and your `processContainer` will get your `data.json` data and you will get the results.

so the problem is your initial state and you can handle it using `loading` flag

Please check this https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-jackson-m8odq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks a lot @NishargShah , I really really appreciate your help for me

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!

Comment: Due to my low reputation, stackoverflow does not allow me to do it :(

Answer (score 2):

If your `fetchAsync` function isn't dependent on anything inside the component, I'd define it outside the component so a new reference isn't created on each render. Then, make sure to call it *inside* the `useEffect` hook.

Edit: Another issue you have is you're trying to access properties on your JSON object before it exists (i.e., before data is fetched). I'd recommend *not* setting an initial value for your adoption object and displaying some sort of loading indicator when it's undefined. See below:

```
async function fetchAsync () {
  let response = await fetch('./data.json');
  let data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

function App() {
  const [adoptionProcess, setAdoptionProcess] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAsync()
      .then(data => setAdoptionProcess(data))
  },[])

  if (!adoptionProcess) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
    <ProcessContainer adoptionProcess={adoptionProcess}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it. I did what you wrote but unfortunately did not work :( still gives the same error

Comment: Oh, interesting. Where is the json located in your project directory?

Comment: it is in public folder. i get the data in the console from app.js as an object with 2 keys. but when i pass the state which holds the data ( adoptionProcess ) to my child component ProcessContainer, it is an empty array. it doesnt hold any data from fetch. how can i pass the data as props from app.js. should i use state ? without it, how can it be possible ?

Comment: can you wrap your data fetching in a try/catch and see if any errors are thrown? Alternatively look in the network panel and see if the fetch is completing correctly

Comment: Are you using a router? If so you'll need to access the resource using an absolute path `await fetch('/data.json');`

Comment: i actually dont know how to wrap data in a try/catch :/. there is no router in the work right now. but i there is await fetch in the function. 

```async function fetchAsync () {
  let response = await fetch('./data.json');
  let data = await response.json();
  return data;
}```

Comment: I took a look at your sandbox. The issue is that you're trying to access properties on the JSON object before it exists (i.e., before the data is fetching). I'll update my answer

Comment: @NishargShah relax. You can see the edit timestamp on my answer was three hours ago.

Comment: No thanks. Feel free to propose a solution that involves several different boolean loading states but this could easily result in data inconsistency. My solution proposes one source of truth for the data's state.

Comment: Nick, Nisharg Shah thank you all for your helps and time for me, I appreciate it

Comment: @Nick yes you are right but remember one thing, always initialize state with something, because adding nothing will cause error in future